# Creating my own object and/or array from json result in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I want to create my own object or array using values from parsed json.

e.g I want my array to look like `[name=>"{value from parsed json object or array}",address=>"{value from parsed json object or array}"]` etc

I'm basically getting results from an api's json and wanting to making my own array or object from the results but not sure how I go about doing this in PHP

```
<?php



    $Consumer_Key = 'xxx';
    $Consumer_Secret = 'xxx';

    if (filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'location')) {
        $maps_url = "http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=$Consumer_Key&maxResults=3&location=" . urlencode($_GET['location']);
        $maps_json = file_get_contents($maps_url);
        $maps_array = json_decode($maps_json, true);

        $lat = $maps_array['results'][0]['locations'][0]['latLng']['lat'];
        $lng = $map1_array['results'][0]['locations'][0]['latLng']['lng'];
        $preferredLocation = $maps_array['results'][0]['providedLocation']['location'];
    }
    ?>



 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <title>Document</title>
 </head>

 <body>
     <form action="" method="GET">
         <input type="text" name="location">
         <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>

     <?php
        if ($maps_array) : ?>
         <h1>Place Searched: <?= $preferredLocation ?></h1>
     <?php endif;
        ?>


     <ul>
         <?php
            if ($maps_array) :
                foreach ($maps_array['results'][0]['locations'] as $val) : ?>
                 <li>County: <?= $val['adminArea4']; ?></li>
                 <li>Lat: <?= $lat; ?></li>
                 <li>Lng: <?= $lng; ?></li>
                 <br>
         <?php endforeach;
            endif;
            ?>
     </ul>





 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Please post your effort, than we'll help you to make it wokrs

Comment: Hi, not sure how to show my effort, as Im not sure what to do. if maybe you could show me with minimial json

Comment: This could help you -> [https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php]

Answer (score 0):

Do these lines

```
$lat = $maps_array['results'][0]['locations'][0]['latLng']['lat'];
$lng = $map1_array['results'][0]['locations'][0]['latLng']['lng'];
$preferredLocation = $maps_array['results'][0]['providedLocation']['location'];
```

return the correct values ?

You can check it with

```
var_dump($lat, $lng, $preferredLocation);
```

If that's okay, you can create your own array as an example

```
$myArray = [
  "lat" => $lat,
  "len" => $len,
  "location" => $preferredLocation
];

//Test output
var_dump($myArray);
```